# Powershell - different encoding result on different computers

Tags: powershell, encoding

Could you tell me please, what depends when you just returning variable in utf8?

```
$error = "žluťoučký kůň"
return $error
```

First is Widnows server 2016, Second Windows 10. Same default encoding, same Powershell version but WS returning trash... I have such a interesting project over a lot of servers but i need this to work. Tell me please what to check...

[image: powershell-error]

[image: powershell-correct]

Thank you!
Michal

Comment: Is the file (the powershell script) saved with UTF8 with a BOM?

Comment: OMG you saved me! I didnt even look this way... Thank you very much.